# Problem printing Kables in loop in flexdashboard

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

The following minimal example fully illustrates the problem. I'm not sure the Loop is actually relevant. This behaviour persists outside loops. From an R file:

```
rmarkdown::render(
  input       = "./test.rmd",
  params      = "-",
  output_file = "./test.html",
  output_dir  = getwd()
)
```

And the test.rmd file looks like this:

````
---
title: "Stack Overflow Question"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```




```{r echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
  ## i <- 1
    # plotlist = list()
    for (i in 1 : 4) {
  
   
      
        
      ## New Tab for Project
      ## -------------------
      cat("\n", "\n# ", "Test ", i,  "\n")
      
      
      ## Column 1
      ## --------
      cat("\n\n", "Column {data-width=250}","\n-------------------------------------\n\n")
      cat("\n", "\n### ", "Plot 1", "\n")
      cat("\n", "\n### ", "Plot 2", "\n")


      ## Column 2
      ## --------
      cat("\n\n", "Column {data-width=250}","\n-------------------------------------\n\n")
      cat("\n", "\n### ", "Plot 3", "\n")
      cat("\n", "\n### ", "Plot 4", "\n")




      ## Column 3
      ## --------
      cat("\n\n", "Column {data-width=500}","\n-------------------------------------\n\n")
      
      
      ## This one works!
      ## ---------------
      cat("\n", "\n### ", "Kable 1", "\n")
      
      mtcars2 <- within(mtcars, {
        vs <- factor(vs, labels = c("V", "S"))
        am <- factor(am, labels = c("automatic", "manual"))
        cyl  <- ordered(cyl)
        gear <- ordered(gear)
        carb <- ordered(carb)
      })
      # summary(mtcars2)
      
     
      # Output
      print(knitr::kable(mtcars2, format = "html"))
      cat('\n\n<!-- -->\n\n')
      
        
      
      ## This one Does not?!
      ## -------------------
      cat("\n", "\n### ", "Kable 2", "\n")

      kable_2 <-
        mtcars2 %>%
        kableExtra::kbl(format = "html",
                        align = "llcllccllc") %>%
        kableExtra::kable_material(
                    lightable_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"),
                    html_font = "sans-serif"
                  )

      if (nrow(mtcars2) > 5) {
        kable_2 <- kable_2 %>%
          kableExtra::scroll_box(height = "400px")
      }
      
      
      # # Why the hell doesn't this work?
      print(kable_2)
      cat('\n\n<!-- -->\n\n')
  }
  
```
````

The output is as follows:

[image]

Why does it print correctly in one case, but not the other. I'd like to have more control over the formatting, for example adding scrolling. And I can't easily do this if everything must be shoved inside the print function...

Comment: kable2 prints without a problem in all for tabs in my environment. Unable to reproduce the problem you depicted in the graphic.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the `knitr` cache?